# Sqlite.swift Get Row Value

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift

I have my query set as such:

`let query = devices.count`

And in order to print the results I have the following:

```
let results = try! db.prepare(query)

            for items in results
            {
            print (items)

            }
```

The output is like this: `Row(columnNames: ["count(*)": 0], values: [Optional(5)])`

How do I just get the `values`?  I want to print out '5'

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using db.scalar

`db.scalar("SELECT count(*) FROM devices")`